# GridView after scroll the ACTION_UP onTouchListener to the child wont call

Tags: android

//child view of GridView in getView() method.
Seems that need to implement custom GridView that will handle the whole scroll and other touch operations on his child. Thanks for any help.

```
class ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
    int position;
    RelativeLayout root;

    public ViewHolder(View v, int position) {
        this.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        this.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        this.root = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        this.position = position;
        image.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("DOWN", "YES");
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("UP", "YES");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you scroll, the touch events are rerouted to the grid view.  When that happens, you'll see an ACTION_CANCEL.  You need to account for this.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use ACTION_CANCEL but it calls everytime on GridView scroll. I need to save the touch even on scrolling and call the ACTION_UP if the finger moves up. ACTION_CANCEL calls in any case on finishing the touch event (on scrolling). I know that the ScrollView intercept the touches of his childs (views inside the Grid) and doesnt return the Action Up on finish...mean to the child.

Comment: Then I think you need to edit your question and be a LOT clearer about what you need.  YOur initial question makes it look like you don't know about cancel.  What you really want is a lot more in depth, and I'm not quite sure exactly what it is yet.